# Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter share trouble

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

I'm trying to do a programatically share via URL and it works fine with some URL addresses but not with another ones.

The ones that I need to work and are not working are these ones:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://pacifico3.dev.arkix.com/site/&t=Arkix

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://pacifico3.dev.arkix.com/site/&title=Arkix

http://twitter.com/share?url=http://pacifico3.dev.arkix.com/site/&text=Arkix

The ones that work well are these ones:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.arkix.com&t=Arkix

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.arkix.com&title=Arkix

http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.arkix.com&text=Arkix

If you test the first ones you will see that the texts are comming well but there are no images comming.

Why does this happens??

Thanks.

Comment: The first set ends on a slash, the second doesn't. If you remove the final slash on the first set, do they work then?

Comment: Just a total guess in the dark, but I found that especially facebook can be very strict about a slash (/) at the end of an url. Did you try removing it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure you URL encode everything after the ? mark

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fpacifico3.dev.arkix.com%2Fsite%2F%26t%3DArkix

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini%3Dtrue%26url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fpacifico3.dev.arkix.com%2Fsite%2F%26title%3DArkix

http://twitter.com/share?url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fpacifico3.dev.arkix.com%2Fsite%2F%26text%3DArkix